# There seems to be a problem with Django Urls?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

When ever I run python manage.py runserver, I get a message in the terminal "Not Found: /base/". I do not have this in my urls to start off with anyways so why am I seeing this? Below is what shows up when I run the server. And my url server is default to "http://127.0.0.1:8000/base/" instead of "http://127.0.0.1:8000".

Using the URLconf defined in cric_manager.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
manager/
The current path, base/, didn’t match any of these.

I tried to restart the termnial, VSCODE, and the webpage, but nothing seems to be working. Its getting a little bit annoying.

Comment: What do you mean with "server default is to ..."?

Comment: Whenever I run "python manage.py runserver" it will now automatically lead to  "http://127.0.0.1:8000/base/" instead of "http://127.0.0.1:8000".

Comment: that is likely just the IDE that opens the browser at that location, you did not change anything w.r.t. the Django server...

Comment: I am still getting  Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/base/
Raised by: django.views.static.serve in all of my other projects as well now. I do not know if messed with something or not.

Comment: In the terminal, its just giving me Not Found: /base/.

Comment: Well, I found an unlikely solution but it works - delate data cache.